# callback value get "error": "2 Unknow: with exepected value

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc

I create a litte gRPC Server.
I will use it as an authentication server with database.

But, when I get the value of callback, I get `"error": "2 UNKNOWN:` + good message ("wrong username" or "wrong password")

Here the source:
proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

package auth;

service Auth {
  rpc onLogin (LoginRequest) returns (LoginResponse);
}

// The request message containing the username and password.

message LoginRequest {
  string username = 1;
  string password = 2;
}

// The response message containing the JWT token.

message LoginResponse {
  string error = 1;
}
```

grpc.js

```
const grpc = require("grpc");
var protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');
const authentication = require("./authentication")

var PROTO_PATH = __dirname + '/auth.proto';

var packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(
    PROTO_PATH,
    {keepCase: true,
    longs: String,
    enums: String,
    defaults: true,
    oneofs: true
    });

var authCredentials = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).auth;

function onLogin(call, callback) 
{
    authentication.grpcLogin(call, callback);
}

module.exports.StartAuthServer = function() {
var server = new grpc.Server();
server.addService(authCredentials.Auth.service, {onLogin: onLogin});
server.bind('0.0.0.0:50051', grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure()); 
server.start();
}
```

authentication.js

```
module.exports.grpcLogin = function(call, callback){
    db.query("select * from users where username = ?" , [call.request.username], function(error, rows){
        if (error)
        return callback({message: error});
        if(!rows.length){
          return callback({
              message: "wrong username" //Error here
          });
        }
        var dbpassword = rows[0].password;
        if(sodium.password_check(dbpassword, call.request.password) === false){
            return callback({
                message: "wrong password" //and here
            });
         }
           //console.log(rows[0]);
           return callback({message: JSON.stringify(rows[0])}); //here too
       });
};
```

On each callback (errors and dababase result), I get the same message.
I dont't know why.

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is? What part of what's happening here is different from what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is standard for Node functions, the gRPC method handler callbacks take an error as the first argument and a success object as the second object. In each case in your code you are passing a non-null first argument, so that is being interpreted as an error and sent to the client as a non-OK status.

If you want to send an error, you should pass either an object with the `details` property set to a string, or an `Error` object constructed with the error details string. In either case you can set the `code` property with a value from `grpc.status`, and the `metadata` property with a `Metadata` object to send those things as part of the error status. Then on the client you will receive an `Error` object describing the error. It will have the corresponding `code` and `metadata` properties, and a `details` property with the original details message. The `message` property will have the code, details, and the name of the code. In the situation you describe, the code is number `2`, `UNKNOWN`, which is the default if the code is not explicitly set.

If you want to just send a message you should pass it as the second argument to the callback.

Comment: I modified the callback as : `return callback(null, {
              error: "wrong username"
          });
` I have no error message ! But now I have a weird response : `"token": "wrong username" or "wrong password"`. I never defined `token`into proto

Comment: That is not what I suggested. If you are trying to send an error you should use the first argument, like you are doing in the question. And you should use the `message` or `details` object key like you are doing in the question, or you can use an actual `Error` object.

Comment: If I use the first argument, like : `return callback({error:"wrong username"}, null);`, I get the same issue. For the second arguments, I do `return callback(null, {error: JSON.stringify(rows[0])});` but still have `token: + my expectedd message`instead of `error : + my expected message`. I need to handle correct message by this way (it's not a error message, so i use the 2nd argument)

Comment: gRPC uses protobuf to define message types. If you are sending a message in gRPC, it has to match the protobuf Message type defined for the method you are using. I think that "token" error you are seeing is actually a protobuf serialization error. I have added some information to my answer explaining the other error you are seeing and how to access your original message when you are sending an error.

Comment: If I use details and gRPC status into details like : ```return callback({
              code: grpc.status.OK,
              details: "wrong username"}, null);          
        }
``` I have now `"error": "13 INTERNAL: Failed to parse server response"` I am investigation on this message

Comment: That error indicates that the client received a message and that the message was corrupted or otherwise improperly serialized. There's no reason to pass `null` to the message parameter, so you should just leave that out.

Comment: I already try `return callback({
                code: grpc.status.OK,
                details: "wrong password"});           
         }
` with no result, same issue

Comment: Sorry, I missed one thing. The OK status indicates that this is not an error, which means that you should be sending a response message. The client expects a response message in that case, which is why it is outputting that error.

Comment: Yes perfect! Thank ;)